# What is the official way to call a function (C/C++) in ab. every 1/100 sec on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer, real-time

I have an asynchronous dataflow system written in C++. In dataflow architecture, the application is a set of component instances, which are initialized at startup, then they communicate each other with pre-defined messages. There is a component type called Pulsar, which provides "clock signal message" to other components which connect to one it (e.g. Delay). It fires message (calls the dataflow dispatcher API) every X ms, where X is the value of the "frequency" parameter, which is given in ms.

**Short, the task is just to call a function (method) in every X ms. The question is: what's the best/official way to do it? Is there any pattern for it?**

There are some methods I found:

- *Use SIGALRM*. I think, signalling is not suits for that purpose. Altough, the resolution is 1 sec, it's too rare.
- *Use HW interrupt*. I don't need this precisity. Also, I aware using HW-related solution (the server is compiled for several platforms, e.g. ARM).
- *Measure elapsed time, and usleep() until next call.* I'm not sure that it's the best way to measure time to call time related system calls by 5 thread, each 10 times in every second - but maybe I'm wrong.
- *Use RealTime kernel functions*. I don't know anything about it. Also, I don't need crystal precise call, it's not an atomreactor, and I can't install RT kernel on some platforms (also, 2.6.x Kernel is available).

Maybe, the best answer is a short commented part of an audio/video player's source code (which I can't find/understand by myself).

*UPDATE (requested by @MSalters): The co-author of the DF project is using Mac OSX, so we should find a solution that works on most Posix-compilant op. systems, not only on Linux. Maybe, in the future there'll be a target device which uses BSD, or some restricted Linux.*

Comment: A signal is appropriate despite your reservations.  Check `man setitimer`, give it a go, and let us know if you have actual issues.  If you're already blocking in something like select(), you may use a timeout value instead.

Comment: Is signalling good choice for a multithread app? When a signal arrives, it should be "dispatched" to the appropiate thread.

Comment: Signal masks are per-thread, so you can block `SIGALRM` in every other thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I think having to have a "pulsar" in what claims to be an asynchronous dataflow system is a design flaw. Either it is asynchronous or it has a synchronizing clock event.

If you have a component that needs a delay, have it request one, through [boost::asio::deadline_timer.async_wait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html) or any of the lower level solutions (select() / epoll() / timer_create() / etc). Either way, the most effective **C++** solution is probably the boost.asio timers, since they would be using whatever is most efficient on your linux kernel version.

Comment: I don't use Boost nor any other libs (only: stdlib, pthreads). We can open an argument on the design; my goal was to keep the Dispatcher (sometimes also called broker, scheduler) as weak as just can be, that's why Pulsar is a separate component. Maybe, a day Dispatcher will provide timer functions/services, but it will feed Pulsars. There are already other special Dispatcher functions, which are accessible thru components (one for example: message ordering). Have to say, that my system is in "prototype" state: it works, but there's lotsa thing to do.

Comment: Well, as far as as-is design goes, I'd go with timer_create() / timer_settime(). Don't forget to put SIGEV_THREAD in sigev_notify for timer_create, so that it delivers timer expirations to thread, rather than process. It would not be a "official C++ way", but it would be "official POSIX way".

Comment: I didn't know that signals are so thread-friendly, I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need hard real-time guarantees, `usleep` should do the job. If you want hard real-time guarantees then an interrupt based or realtime kernel based function will be necessary.

Comment: usleep is obsolete you should be using nanosleep or select

Comment: Nanosleep is cool, it tells the remaining time upon interruption, but I need to call a time read function yet every round to correct the amount to sleep, and I don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the previously mentioned approaches is to use the [Timer FD](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) support in Linux Kernels 2.6.25+ (pretty much any distribution that's close to "current"). Timer FDs provide a bit more flexibility than the previous approaches.

Comment: Yep, It's so cool! But I don't want to drop BSD compatibility (my friend, who is co-author in this project, is using Mac, unfortunatelly).

Comment: @ern0: Please add such concerns to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting the question of design (which I think is an interesting question, but deserves its own thread)...

I would start off by designing an 'interrupt' idea, and using signals or some kernel function to interrupt every X usec. I would delay doing sleep-functions until the other ideas were too painful.